# Struts 2.5.10.1 migration issue

Tags: struts2, classnotfoundexception

```
Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger"
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:114)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1026)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:987)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:83)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:608)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:540)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:114)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1026)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:987)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:83)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:608)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:540)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Comment: very nice question

Comment: This question is poorly asked.  See [ask] for how to improve it.  Probably belongs in Superuser instead.